# php регулярное выражение из ссылок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть большая строка где висит несколько ссылок:

```
<a href="/asd/bla bla-32679">
<a href="/pds/bib bla-65437">
<a href="/yte/rar kop-750321">
<a href="/zxc/MODEL-75943">
```

и кроме этих строк всякий мусор, подскажите каким рег выражением можно вытащить цифры в каждой из ссылок? т.е 32679,65437,750321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="/asd/bla bla-32679">
<a href="/pds/bib bla-65437">
<a href="/yte/rar kop-750321">
<a href="/zxc/MODEL-75943">';
$pattern = '/<a\s+href=[\'"][^\'"\d]+(\d+)[\'"][\>]*>/s';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $out);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out[1]);
```

Comment: распознает но не все( например <a href="/zxc/model-75943"> не распознает

Comment: @user214958 можете дополнить вопрос той строкой, которая не распознается?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @user214958 у меня отлавливаются все четыре числа. Немного поправил регулярное выражение в своем ответе, но чтобы быть до конца уверенным, нужно воспроизвести ситуацию, попробуйте подобрать пример, на котором приведенное выше выражение сломается - тогда я смогу его адаптировать под этот случай.